# Control tick labels in Python seaborn package

Tags: python, pandas, ipython, seaborn

I have a scatter plot matrix generated using the `seaborn` package and I'd like to remove all the tick mark labels as these are just messying up the graph (either that or just remove those on the x-axis), but I'm not sure how to do it and have had no success doing Google searches.  Any suggestions?

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.pairplot(wheat[['area_planted',
    'area_harvested',
    'production',
    'yield']])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
import seaborn as sns
iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")
g = sns.pairplot(iris)
g.set(xticklabels=[])
```

[image]

Comment: this solution didn't work for me. instead i did it through matplotlib: `matplotlib.setp(plot_object.set_yticklabels([]))`

Answer (score 4):

You can use a list comprehension to loop through all columns and turn off visibility of the xaxis.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1000, 2)) * 1e6
sns.pairplot(df)
```

[image]

```
plot = sns.pairplot(df)
[plot.axes[len(df.columns) - 1][col].xaxis.set_visible(False) 
 for col in range(len(df.columns))]
plt.show()
```

[image]

You could also rescale your data to something more readable:

```
df /= 1e6
sns.pairplot(df)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Probably using the following is more appropriate

```
import seaborn as sns


iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")
g = sns.pairplot(iris)
g.set(xticks=[])
```